# Compute Engine and update sor sysadmin

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, system-administration

I will ask one question about compute engine. Actually, i deploy 3 app on app engine but and would like to migrate to compute engine. I would like to know if google manages the updates of the OS automatically because I do not want to manage all the problems relating to SysAdmin.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud has an OS patch management service.

1. [Best practices for OS updates at scale](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/best-practices-for-os-patch-management-on-compute-engine)
2. [OS patch management](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-patch-management)
3. [OS configuration management](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-config-management)